# Any algorithm to find the shortest path/distance in android?

Tags: android, algorithm

I am new to android and I am doing some project planning.

To finish the planning, I have to know which algorithms or techniques that I will use in my project. The idea is very simple. I just want to determine the shortest path/distance that between my current location and few supermarkets location.

Are there any algorithms or Android API I can apply?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't know about Android API, but if there is something you should be able to find it on google. For example  try to look at "google map api", and if you can get directions and distances with the api easily.

Look for exemple at the [Google direction API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/directions/)

Or even better : [google distance matrix api](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/distancematrix/)  it gives you the distance of any given set of points.(for example a matrix with at each row : [your position, one supermarket)

> **for example :** if I am *20 passage de la bonne graine* in paris and I
>   want to check how far is the *monoprix (supermarket 5 Rue
>   Godefroy Cavaignac)* I can request something like that : 
>   http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=20%20passage%20de%20la%20bonne%20graine&destinations=45%20Rue%20Godefroy%20Cavaignac,%2075011%20Paris,%20France&mode=walking&language=fr-FR&sensor=false

In term of algorithm you can process as below:

create a graph:

- each road is a edge
- each suppermarket is a node
- your position is a node

then apply [Dijktra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) to find the shortest path between your position and all supermarkets

Here is a nice illustration (from wikipedia) on how Dijktra's algorithm works :

[image]

hope it helps

Comment: using Disktra's algoritm, the shortest path means the distance between current position and each supermarkets, or means current position -> supermarket A -> supermarket B -> supermarket C?

Comment: @red23jordan it's just between 2 points : current position and supermarket A , current position and supermarket B ...Etc. (current position and each supermarket) . But honestly google API seems pretty complete, so you might not need this algorithm.

Comment: thx very much, if google API is good enough, then there may be no need to use Dijktra's algorithm.

Comment: @red23jordan you're welcome, I tested it with some random supermarkets around my position and it seems to work perfectly. (but be carefull of the mode of transportation you're specifying, there might not be easy way by car or bicycling but it works by walking)

Comment: I have visited the Google direction API, however, I don't know how to apply this API to android... is it just a web API or android built-in API?

Comment: @red23jordan it's just a web api. In android you will send an Http request and use the return in JSON or XML