# How to calculate distance between a marker and a Polilyne path on Google Maps API v2 for Android?

Tags: android, api, google-maps, distance

I'm new to Android development and Google Maps API, so I'd like to know how it'd be possible to calculate the distance between a marker and a Polilyne path.

To give you an idea, the application has to basically tell the user which Polilyne path (there's like 10) is closer to the marker set by the user on the map.

Answer (score 0):

```
    private double distance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2, char unit)
{
    double theta = lon1 - lon2;
    double dist = Math.sin(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.sin(deg2rad(lat2)) + Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(theta));
    dist = Math.acos(dist);
    dist = rad2deg(dist);
    dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;
    if (unit == 'K') {
        dist = dist * 1.609344;
    } else if (unit == 'N') {
        dist = dist * 0.8684;
    }
    return (dist);
}
```

This function can be used to measure distance between two points, can return metric or imperial units.
Just try to iterate the points of the polyline and the minimal distance between the polyline points and the closest point of the polyline and the marker will be the distance. (Or you can use the average)

Answer (score -1):

There are many algorithms to find shortest distance from current location to a polyline or polygon. One you can find @ https://stackoverflow.com/a/7803519