# Google Maps Driving route android

Tags: android, google-maps

I need to plot a route from user's current location to the destination address. Now let's say if the user takes a different route, I need to replot the route. How should I proceed?

I, obviously, will not keep on plotting the route as soon as the user's location. I need to replot only when the user takes a different route

Answer (score 0):

Have already been answered here. 
[How to draw interactive Polyline on route google maps v2 android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17425499/how-to-draw-interactive-polyline-on-route-google-maps-v2-android)

Code sample

```
PolylineOptions options = new  
            PolylineOptions().width(5).color(Color.BLUE).geodesic(true);
for (int z = 0; z < list.size(); z++) {
   LatLng point = list.get(z);
   options.add(point);
}
line = myMap.addPolyline(options);
```

Comment: It will just draw the polyline. I need to redraw the path if the user takes a different route. Is there a way I can detect if user is on the drawn path or he is using a different path

Comment: This feature is available in new Google Maps Navigation. I want similar feature

Comment: Okay how about if your get your current location and calculate the distance between polyline and current location. If it meets a certain threshold then redraw the line from your current location to your destination.

Comment: Its not that simple what you are trying to achieve. Have a look at this link. I think thats what you are looking for. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7803474/any-algorithm-to-find-the-shortest-path-distance-in-android/7803519#7803519

Comment: How would I calculate distance between curent location and polyline?

Comment: Read my last comment.